# docker pull command doesn't allow password and always getting Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-command, docker-pull

I am going through a unexpected error. I am always getting the error "Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required" whenever I am trying to pull `microsoft/mssql-server-windows:2017-latest` by using the blow command.

`C:\Users\Administrator>docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-windows:2017-latest`

Surprisingly I am able to login when I use `docker login`, I am not sure what I am missing here. I am also able to login to https://hub.docker.com/ with the credentials I have. The problem exists only when I try pull.

> C:\Users\Administrator>**docker pull**
>   microsoft/mssql-server-windows:2017-latest
>
> Please login prior to pull: Login with your Docker ID to push and pull
>   images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to
>   https://hub.docker.com to create one. Username: sibeeshvenu Password:
>   Error response from daemon: unauthorized: authentication required
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>**docker login** Login with your Docker ID to push
>   and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head
>   over to https://hub.docker.com to create one. Username: sibeeshvenu
>   Password: **Login Succeeded**
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>**docker pull**
>   microsoft/mssql-server-windows:2017-latest
>
> Please login prior to pull: Login with your Docker ID to push and pull
>   images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to
>   https://hub.docker.com to create one. Username (sibeeshvenu):
>   sibeeshvenu Password: Error response from **daemon: unauthorized**:
>   authentication required
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason. It was the problem with the repository name. I searched for `mmsql` in the [hub.docker](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=mssql-server&starCount=0), there I could not find any repositories with the name `microsoft/mssql-server-windows:2017-latest` and I [selected](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/) `mssql-server-windows-express`  and run the pull command as below.

`docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express`

After I enter my credentials it was pulling the repository as expected. It seems like we get this authorize error when the repository name is invalid.

> C:\Users\Administrator>docker pull
>   microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express Using default tag: latest
>   latest: Pulling from microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
>   3889bb8d808b: Extracting [======================================>
>   ] 3.127 GB/4.07 GB 449343c9d7e2: Download complete a336350523ea:
>   Download complete 2c12ef99f411: Download complete 8ebb28bb3276:
>   Download complete 3bb8431b46ce: Download complete a4a938096b3c:
>   Download complete 656eb837f7e6: Download complete a3d536b0e79d:
>   Download complete a0aec5f46615: Download complete 64a0f6512541:
>   Download complete b900d04a68bd: Download complete